# Postman, Python and passing images and metadata to a web service

Tags: python, postman, flask-restful

this is a two-part question: I have seen individual pieces discussed, but can't seem to get the recommended suggestions to work together. I want to create a web service to store images and their metadata passed from a caller and run a test call from Postman to make sure it is working. So to pass an image (Drew16.jpg) to the web service via Postman, it appears I need something like this:

[image: Postman Configuration]

For the web service, I have some python/flask code to read the request (one of many variations I have tried):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse

...

def post(self, name):
    request_data = request.get_json()
    userId = request_data['UserId']
    type = request_data['ImageType']
    image = request.files['Image']
```

Had no problem with the data portion and straight JSON but adding the image has been a bugger. Where am I going wrong on my Postman config? What is the actual set of Python commands for reading the metadata and the file from the post? TIA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pardon the almost blog post. I am posting this because while you can find partial answers in various places, I haven't run across a complete post anywhere, which would have saved me a ton of time. The problem is you need both sides to the story in order to verify either.

So I want to send a request using Postman to a Python/Flask web service. It has to have an image along with some metadata.

Here are the settings for Postman (URL, Headers):

[image]

And Body:

[image]

Now on to the web service. Here is a bare bones service which will take the request, print the metadata and save the file:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)        

# POST - just get the image and metadata
@app.route('/RequestImageWithMetadata', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    request_data = request.form['some_text']
    print(request_data)
    imagefile = request.files.get('imagefile', '')
    imagefile.save('D:/temp/test_image.jpg')
    return "OK", 200

app.run(port=5000)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Very valid comment. Thanks for this.

Comment: It shows 'NoneTyoe' object is not subscriptable.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure `request.files['Image'] contains the image you are sending and follow http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/ to save the file to your file system. Something like

```
file = request.files['Image']
file.save('./test_image.jpg')
```

might do what you want, while you will have to work out the details of how the file should be named and where it should be placed.