# Postman stuck when sending post request to Flask on second time

Tags: python, opencv, flask, postman

I am creating an application where I have to read images from a POST call in Flask. I am using the instructions as provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779424/postman-python-and-passing-images-and-metadata-to-a-web-service) for setting Postman. My Flask code looks like follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session
import cv2

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    r = request
    # convert string of image data to uint8
    # decode image
    imagefile = request.files.get('imagefile', '')
    imagefile.save('temp.jpg')
    img = cv2.imread('temp.jpg')
    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return ("SUCCESS")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

The program runs fine on calling it for the first time and displays the image correctly, but when I try to call it again without rerunning the python code it gets stuck on sending request. Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to correct it. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with the Postman application for Linux.

**EDIT**

As suggested by @[MaxTryk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2646552/maxtryk) I tried adding breakpoints to find the culprit and it is the image showing section.

```
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I still don't have any ideas why these statements are causing the second request to hang, so if you know any way to correct it please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If rerunning the python code solves the issue, the problem must be the code, not Postman - I'd suggest to debug by placing breakpoints to see where the execution hangs up.